# Can I build a dynamic SQL query from table entries (tablename, column, selections for WHERE statement)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic

I need to build a dynamic query to import data to Azure DataFactory, using a couple of tables as the query source (I already have a pipeline that imports the tables "as-is", based on the list of source table in SQL).

This currently uses SQL Server 2014, as that's what I have on my dev system.

One table contains the list of source tables to be imported, whilst the second contains a list of filters for each table.

To make it slightly more complex, there could be multiple options for each inclusion, based on a 'Counter' column.

SourceTable:

```
TableName
---------
Table1
Table2
Table3
```

QueryTable:

```
TableName  ColumnName  Counter  Value
--------------------------------------
Table1,    Column1,    1,       abc
Table2,    Column1,    1,       def
Table2,    Column1,    2,       ghi
Table2,    Column1,    3,       jkl
Table3,    Column1,    1,       mno
Table3,    Column2,    1,       pqr
```

So in this case, I would be looking to generate something like the below into a separate table to be read by an Azure pipeline:

(Based on selecting * from [SourceTables].[TableName] join [QueryTable] on SourceTable.TableName = QueryTable.TableName)

```
select * from Table1 where Column1 in ('abc')
select * from Table2 where Column1 in ('def','ghi','jkl')
select * from Table3 where Column1 in ('mno') and Column2 in ('pqr')
```

If there are any pointers, I would appreciate the help.

NB: For right now, I "only" really need to make the first 2 scenarios 2 work (single/multiple entries against the same column), although scenario 3 is entirely possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do all your values, in the table `QueryTable` really all have commas (`,`) at the end of them?

Comment: No.  That was my formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is *real* ugly, I'm not going to lie. Honestly, I would suggest fixing the design here, but (saying that) you *can* achieve what you are after. This is far from "simple" to understand though, as this achieve the result with an aggregated string inside an aggregated string:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable (--SchemaName sysname DEFAULT N'dbo', --This appears to be missing
                            TableName sysname,
                            ColumnName sysname,
                            Counter int,
                            Value varchar(128)); 

INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable (TableName,ColumnName,Counter, Value)
VALUES(N'Table1',N'Column1',1,'abc'),
      (N'Table2',N'Column1',1,'def'),
      (N'Table2',N'Column1',2,'ghi'),
      (N'Table2',N'Column1',3,'jkl'),
      (N'Table3',N'Column1',1,'mno'),
      (N'Table3',N'Column2',1,'pqr');
GO

DECLARE @CRLF nchar(2) = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10);
DECLARE @AND nchar(7) = @CRLF + N'  AND ';

SELECT N'SELECT *' + @CRLF +
       N'FROM dbo.' + QUOTENAME(TableName) + @CRLF + 
       N'WHERE ' +
       STUFF((SELECT @AND + N' ' + QUOTENAME(sq1.ColumnName) + N' IN (' + 
                     STUFF((SELECT N',' + QUOTENAME(sq2.Value,'''')
                            FROM dbo.YourTable sq2
                            WHERE sq2.TableName = YT.TableName
                              AND sq2.ColumnName = sq1.ColumnName
                            ORDER BY Counter ASC
                            FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('(./text())[1]','nvarchar(MAX)'),1,1,'') +
                     N')'
              FROM dbo.YourTable sq1
              WHERE sq1.TableName = YT.TableName
              GROUP BY sq1.ColumnName
              ORDER BY sq1.ColumnName
              FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('(./text())[1]','nvarchar(MAX)'),1,LEN(@AND)+1,'') + N';'
FROM dbo.YourTable YT
GROUP BY TableName;

GO
DROP TABLE dbo.YourTable;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b1bea38361937df12e4d304f691593e6)

Note that if `[Value]` can have a value longer than 128 characters, you'll need to wrap the value in single quotes (`'`) and `REPLACE` those inside them. Also, it it's an `nvarchar` (not a `varchar`) you'll need to prefix those single quotes with an `nvarchar` notation character (`N`).

Comment: Thanks Larnu.
The table that you have as [YourTable] already exists in my dev server as [QueryTable], but I need that to join to the [SourceTable] table that I mentioned.
So basically, I need to read the [TableName] column from [SourceTable], then check for any corresponding filters in [QueryTable] when joined on the [TableName] column in each.

Comment: You can `JOIN` to `SourceTable` if you "need" to @PieEyed, but considering it has one column, and the same values as that in `QueryTable` I saw no need in the solution.

Comment: Sorry.  My fault.
It's there because not every table has filters.

Comment: OK, then you can add a `JOIN` or `EXISTS` as needed, @PieEyed ; it doesn't change the underlying solution.